# Problemas ao contactar o domain Controller

Tags: c#

Eu fiz um programa que acessa a directorias na rede. Esse programa utiliza a API do windows `WNetAddConnection2`. Um exemplo de implementação desta API [está disponivel em `C#` no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197430/1698682). Fica aqui o código para referencia:

```
public class NetworkConnection : IDisposable
{
    string _networkName;

    public NetworkConnection(string networkName, 
        NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        _networkName = networkName;

        var netResource = new NetResource()
        {
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
            RemoteName = networkName
        };

        var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
            ? credentials.UserName
            : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

        var result = WNetAddConnection2(
            netResource, 
            credentials.Password,
            userName,
            0);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(result);
        }   
    }

    ~NetworkConnection()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
    }

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource, 
        string password, string username, int flags);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
        bool force);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NetResource
{
    public ResourceScope Scope;
    public ResourceType ResourceType;
    public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
    public int Usage;
    public string LocalName;
    public string RemoteName;
    public string Comment;
    public string Provider;
}

public enum ResourceScope : int
{
    Connected = 1,
    GlobalNetwork,
    Remembered,
    Recent,
    Context
};

public enum ResourceType : int
{
    Any = 0,
    Disk = 1,
    Print = 2,
    Reserved = 8,
}

public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
{
    Generic = 0x0,
    Domain = 0x01,
    Server = 0x02,
    Share = 0x03,
    File = 0x04,
    Group = 0x05,
    Network = 0x06,
    Root = 0x07,
    Shareadmin = 0x08,
    Directory = 0x09,
    Tree = 0x0a,
    Ndscontainer = 0x0b
}
```

Normalmente esta API funciona sem problemas. Contudo entre duas máquinas da minha rede (e até agora, somente estas) o problema `System.IO.IOException: The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later.` ocorre. Quais são os motivos que podem levar este problema ocorrer e como o posso resolver?

Comment: Tive problemas com um serviço quando precisamos utilizar protocolo seguro. No meu caso, não estava expondo o endpoint corretamente e, consequentemente o serviço não conseguia alcançar o controlador. Espero que ajude.

Comment: @AndreMesquita Pode explicar exatamente o que é "expor o endpoint corretamente"? O que é que voce fez?

Comment: Bruno, na ocasião usei este how-to para me orientar sobre a configuração do endpoint. [HOW-TO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl).

Answer (score 0):

Tive vários problemas ao lidar com directorias em redes e gostava de deixar uma lista de recomendações que deverão ser seguidas, se você usar a mesma API que eu usei.

1. Em certo ponto a sua conexão pode deixar de funcionar, se isto acontecer você deverá fechar a sua ligação actual e abrir uma nova
2. Você também pode ter problemas a fechar a ligação, caso isso aconteça, tente novamente
3. Especifique sempre o nome do host nas suas credencias